# Building a contingency table

Tags: r, loops, contingency

I have a data like this:

```
A  B
1 10 
1 20
1 30
2 10
2 30
2 40
3 20
3 10
3 30
4 20
4 10
5 10
5 10
```

and I want to build a contingency table like this:

```
   10 20 30 40
10 1   3  2  0
20 3   0  2  0
30 2   2  0  0
40 0   0  0  0
```

Meaning: According to column A, for each two values of column B mark + 1 in the specific Contingency table.

Can you help me do this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. How is 'for each two values of column B' defined when A has three rows with the same value? And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: example in the image:

Comment: I don't see an image. If you mean the example output you gave, it's very hard to deduce how it came about. For instance, 40 is in column B but nowhere in your contingency table.

Comment: here : https://goo.gl/P3CcpZ
Thank you so much for your help. You can ignor the other example.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Please give a proper example and step-by-step explanation what you're trying to do. Start with the simplest case: how should the data when A is 1 be processed?

Comment: Hey,
According to column A:

10 & 10 - mark +1 in the correct cell in the table.

10& 30 - mark +1 in the correct cell in the table

later in "2": 

10&20 - mark +1 in the correct cell in the table.

et cetera

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very ugly answer, using the data from the image, because I already spent too much time on your problem. In general, it's not practical to have your result depend on the order of variables.

```
A <- rep(c(1:4),c(3,2,3,3))
B <- c(10,10,30,10,20,30,20,10,10,20,30)
data <- data.frame(cbind(A,B))

#split by A
library(plyr)
data2 <- ddply(data,.(A),function(x){
  combined_pairs <- cbind(x$B[-nrow(x)],
                          x$B[-1])
  #return data where first is always lowest
  smallest <- apply(combined_pairs,MARGIN=1,
                    FUN=min)
  largest <- apply(combined_pairs,MARGIN=1,
                   FUN=max)
  return(data.frame(small=smallest,large=largest))
})


library(reshape2)

result <- dcast(small~large,data=data2, 
                fun.aggregate=length) 
> result
  small 10 20 30
1    10  1  3  1
2    20  0  0  2
```

I think you can add the empty rows yourself if you still need them.